# How to use Str_Replace on Array Items in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know how to replace an Apostrophe from a String with a space, in php. 
However how can I remove Apostrophes in arrays items?

```
  //Example replacing Apostrophe with space
  $string = str_replace("'", "", $escapestring); 


 if ( $f_pointer === false )
    die ("invalid URL");

 $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
 while(! feof($f_pointer))
 {
      $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);

      //DO REPLACE HERE BEFORE INSERTION INTO SQL STATEMENT
      $sql="INSERT INTO x
             (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
            values('$array[0]','$array[1]','$array[2]',
                   'array[3]','array[4]','array[5]')";
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I understand that, I'm a beginner trying to gain a better understanding of mysql

Comment: To gain a better under standing you should [not use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You should be using prepared statements but in the rare instance  you have to manually escape something that is going to be part of a  query use the database specific escaping function.

Comment: `values('$array[0]','$array[1]','$array[2]',
                   'array[3]','array[4]','array[5]')"; ` you can do so `values('" . implode("','", $array) . "'";`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED answer:

You want to remove apostrophe for your query. It's a better way to use function as mysqli_real_escape_string:

"(PHP 5)
mysqli::real_escape_string -- mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection" | http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

So you directly protect your query input against sql injection. See the following example:

```
$itemsToClean = ["Value with '", "Second value with '"];
// With older PHP version, you cannot use [], but use array() instead

$cleanItems = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $itemsToClean);

print_r($cleanItems);
```

Comment: Could you add comments in your comment if thats ok, im struggling to understand how to deal with my $ar[0]','$ar[1]','$ar[2]','$ar[3]','$ar[4]','$ar[5 ] array values with your example

Answer (score 1):

use str_replace with array as subject

```
$itemsToClean = ["Value with '", "Second value with '"];

$itemsToClean = str_replace("'", '', $itemsToClean);

print_r($itemsToClean);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Value with 
    [1] => Second value with 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that huge help, just wondering why is arg[5] in the results contain a Apostrophe?
$ar = str_replace("'", '', $ar);

print_r($ar);
    [0] => -
    [1] => Mary
    [2] => E
    [3] => 7:21 AM
    [4] => 
    [5] => WOMENS
Result
INSERT INTO womenscores(id,name,score,time,round,game)values('-','Mary','E','7:21 AM','','WOMEN'S')

Comment: ie. after str_replace it is absent but  appears after?

Comment: https://eval.in/409202  set input data there and look result. I am ready to improve the code if error will be

Comment: Sorry, I use $ar = str_replace("'", '', $ar); in the while looop, and I print out the  $ar and it's fine & Apostrophe is removed .....But when I do my inserts using  $ar[0]...$ar[5]... The Apostrophe appears.